# Magento : invoice print gives blank page on backend

Tags: php, magento

I have upgraded magento from 1.4 to 1.7.2, everything is working well,but when admin try to 
print invoice on backend , it gives a blank page, nothing in error logs

I tried to change construct function to

```
abstract public function __construct($filePath);
```

in lib/zend/pdf/FileParserDataSource.php , but still it is not working.

Comment: I am now getting [Thu Dec 26 16:52:37 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 519573504 bytes) error.. need a help

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out `__construct` and `__deconstruct` lines. You're probably using PHP 5.4 and there is some incompatibility with Zendframework.